# how to insert a return variable from a function to a HTML form

Tags: javascript

I am working on html form post to redirect people to a website using SSO. The username is directly getting from the registry. However, I am not sure why the value is not able to insert into the form value. Can someone please advise. Much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script>

var username;
var test;

function submitForm() {
    document.forms["ciqForm"].submit();
}

function getUsername() {
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    username = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Plugin\\username");
    // username = "albert@xxx.com"
    return username;
}


// document.getElementbyName('extRedirUserName').value=getUsername();
document.forms['myForm'].elements['extRedirUserName'].value=getUsername();

</script>
<body onload="submitForm()">
    <h1>Redirecting.</h1>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST" action="https://www.somewebsite.com">
        <input type="hidden" id="hello" name="extRedirUserName" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="extRedirPassword" value= "password" />
    </form>
</body>
</head>
```

`

Comment: you are submitting the form on load ,  `<body onload="submitForm()">`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are not using right form ID/Name ?

```
document.forms["ciqForm"].submit();
```

but here

```
form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is not yet fully loaded when you are running
     document.forms['myForm'].elements['extRedirUserName'].value=getUsername();

Try adding it as the first line in the submitForm function (which is executed after the document was already).
I assume you already checked that the username is being received using this method.

Answer (score 0):

With some changes:

```
        var username;
        var test;

        function submitForm() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();//you can change this with your code
        }

        function getUsername() {
            var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            username = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Plugin\\username");
            // username = "albert@xxx.com"
            return username;
        }


        // document.getElementbyName('extRedirUserName').value=getUsername();
        document.forms['myForm'].elements['extRedirUserName'].value=getUsername();

    submitForm();//call here
        </script>
        <body >
            <h1>Redirecting.</h1>
            <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="POST" action="https://www.somewebsite.com">
                <input type="hidden" id="hello" name="extRedirUserName" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="extRedirPassword" value= "password" />
            </form>
        </body>
        </head>
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. However, I tried the changes you have made but for some reason, the username get returned still showing "null" value. Do you know how I should modify the code in order to make the DOM fully loaded before getting the username?

Comment: I am sure that this is related to `getUsername()` Make sure your request is correct .